# Inputting a String Argument as a Variable in function giving a NameError

Tags: python

I have this code block that it should give out the CIK number when the stock ticker is supplied:

```
def lookup_cik(ticker, name=None):
    good_read = False
    ticker = ticker.strip().upper()
    url = 'http://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?action+getcompany&CIK=(cik)&count=10&output=xml'.format(cik=ticker)

    try:
        xmlFile = urlopen ( url )
        try:
            xmlData = xmlFile.read()
            good_read = True
        finally:
            xmlFile.close()
    except HTTPError as e:
        print( "HTTP Error:", e.code )
    except URLError as e:
        print( "URL Error:", e.reason )
    except TimeoutError as e:
        print( "Timeout Error:", e.reason )
    except socket.timeout:
        print( "Socket Timeout Error" )
    if not good_read:
        print( "Unable to lookup CIK for ticker:", ticker )
        return
    try:
        root = ET.fromstring(xmlData)
    except ET.ParseError as perr:
        print( "XML Parser Error:", perr )

    try:
        cikElement = list(root.iter( "CIK" ))[0]
        return int(cikElement.text)
    except StopIteration:
        pass
```

However when it try to input a Stock ticker i get

```
>>> lookup_cik(BDX)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#34>", line 1, in <module>
    lookup_cik(BDX)
NameError: name 'BDX' is not defined
```

I know that it is a `NameError` but i have never met an issue where the function does not recognize the supposedly inputted argument data the stock ticker which in our example is BDX.

Comment: How is BDX defined? You're not quoting it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function expects a *string*, so pass in one:

```
lookup_cik("BDX")
```

Without the quotes Python parses that as a *name*, but you never bound anything to that name (assigned to it).

Note that you'll also get a `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'root' referenced before assignment` exception if there was a parse error. You probably want to exit the function at that point:

```
try:
    root = ET.fromstring(xmlData)
except ET.ParseError as perr:
    print( "XML Parser Error:", perr )
    return
```

You'll most likely get a parse error, because you never actually interpolate the ticker anywhere in the string; you are missing a `{cik}` placeholder:

```
url = 'http://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?action+getcompany&CIK=(cik)&count=10&output=xml'.format(cik=ticker)
```

You probably meant to use `CIK={cik}` there. A quick experiment directly calling the site also shows you need to use `action=getcompany` (`=` instead of `+`):

```
url = 'http://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?action=getcompany&CIK={cik}&count=10&output=xml'.format(cik=ticker)
```

Because you use `list()` on `root.iter()`, the whole expression will not raise `StopIteration` (`list()` catches that). Instead, the expression *could* raise a `IndexError` instead.

I'd use `next()` there instead:

```
cikElement = next(root.iter("CIK"), None)
return cikElement and int(cikElement.text)
```

or better still, just use [`Element.find()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.find):

```
cikElement = root.find("CIK")
return cikElement and int(cikElement.text)
```

Comment: Oh shame on me! Ohhh anyway this question may help somebody i think we should keep it

Comment: Thank you so much. Not only you have answered the question you went behind enemy lines too!